# Should I keep MongoDB connection alive if I'm adding a record every 10 seconds?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've written a small Node.js script that tests a part my company's API latency - specifically latency for chat messages every 10 seconds. I need to store this data and I think MongoDB is probably my only realistic option. It's a tiny bit of data that I need to store, only 1 number and a timestamp.

So that made me wonder... Should I leave the MongoDB connection alive, constantly, only having a rest when I happen to restart the script (or when it crashes), or should I connect and disconnect every 10 seconds? If it helps, the MongoDB will be on the same server and it will only be storing this data for now (I mean it's a fresh install).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to store only a number and a timestamp, I would have a look at Redis. Redis is a key/value store and since redis is rather memory oriented it's really good for frequently updated real-time data, such as statistics for example.

I've been mostly using mongodb lately, and its really fast aswell but a litte more feature-rich nosql db than Redis, and therefor maybe a bit slower in this scenario.

*- Should I leave the MongoDB connection alive*
Yes, that is fine and typical behavior. Open the connection once, and make queries against it for as long as you want. When your node.js process dies it will automatically be closed.

Comment: Great - I'll look into Redis, it looks quite appropriate for this. Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, if you are using Redis make sure you have enough memory to store the all data. Your case seems to be more suitable for MongoDB, as you don't need as fast "read" queries.